# Double digit month date validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have 3 textboxes like below

```
<input type="text" name="birth_year" id="birth_year" maxLength="4" size="4">Year 
<input type="text" name="birth_month" id="birth_month" maxLength="2" size="2">Month
<input type="text" name="birth_day" id="birth_day" maxLength="2" size="2">Day

[2012] Year [09] Month [13] Day
```

How can I validate that date with JQ?

I've been searching for it for two days.

I couldn't find anything that had the format like this XXXX-XX-XX, though.

I found [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dceast/vmHjN/) but this one doesn't validate two digit month or day like 03 or 22

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You don't need jQuery to perform good ol' fashioned javascript validation.  Read the string values and parse it into an integer.  Check if it is in the expected range of values.  If nothing seems out of place, it's valid.

Comment: Are you validating that the user has entered "01" not just "1" - if so, you would be better of padding the value. If you need to validate that "01" or "1" are valid, @Neil is right about parsing the value. `var monthValue = parseInt(month, 10);`

Comment: Do you need to check that it is an actual date, or just that the numbers are within range?  For example, would February 29, 2012 be valid and February 29, 2013 NOT be valid?

Comment: I want to check that it is an actual date. I am trying to follow Sonhee's suggestion. It seems to work fine but I am not quite sure if that is right.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually very simple:

```
var year = document.getElementsByName("birth_year")[0].value,
    month = document.getElementsByName("birth_month")[0].value,
    day = document.getElementsByName("birth_day")[0].value,
    date = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);

if (isNaN(date.getTime())) {
    // The date is invalid
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in older browsers like IE8, because they don't accept the yyyy-mm-dd date format. But you can rewrite the date like this:

```
var date = new Date(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
```

(I think the format mm/dd/yyyy makes no sense, but well... This is how Javascript works since its first definition.)

Comment: Let me just try that. Anyway, thank you so much! Really appreciate it!

Comment: If it works for you, you can accept the answer (and upvote if you feel like it).

Answer (score 0):

A better validation (see [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6cw8C/2/)). If you are going to ask for birthdays, why not check if they are plausible too?. The first part checks for invalid dates (out-of-range, including date outside that month's specific range); the second part outs people that are as-yet unborn, or way too old to be plausible.

```
/**
 * input is year/month/day (month from 1 to 12, day from 1 to 31)
 * output is boolean: true if correct and in-range, false if not
 */
function isValidBirthdate(year, month, day, minAge, maxAge) {
  // javascript days expect zero-based days and months
  month --; day --;
  var saysWasBorn = new Date(year, month, day);
  if (saysWasBorn.getDate() != day
    || saysWasBorn.getMonth() != month
    || saysWasBorn.getFullYear() != year) {
        console.log("impossible date: ");     
        return false;
  }
  var now = new Date();
  var yearsOld = now.getFullYear() - saysWasBorn.getFullYear();
  if ((now.getMonth()*40 + now.getDate() - 1) < 
      (saysWasBorn.getMonth()*40 + saysWasBorn.getDate())) {
     yearsOld --;                
  }
  if (yearsOld > maxAge) {
    console.log("too old");        
    return false;
  } else if (yearsOld < minAge) {
    console.log("too young");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I think the interesting part end after the first `if`, the rest are unrequested checks. And `Date` objects do **not** expect zero-based days, only months.

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest and help. I am not just gonna copy and paste it. I am a novice but trying to understand things and reuse it by altering as needed. Thanks again! :)